# Apps Script: Change data into a specific format

Tags: google-apps-script

I have phone numbers being copied and paste into column H by the user in 5 different formats. I want to re-write all these numbers when they are being inserted **or** after they have been inserted

- From:

```
=494079712400
=+494076122122
431 84500
tel: +49 40 63305-5040
040 / 853 123 – 48
```

To:

```
04079712400
04076122122
0431 84500
040 63305 5040
040 853 123 48
```

In other words, for each phone number I want to **keep only the numeric characters** (so, from 0 to 9) **and add a leading zero**, if there isn´t already a leading zero in it. The formula I´ve been using so far and which is almost identical to the one suggested in the comment section, can help me get rid of some of the non-numeric characters, but it doesn´t add the leading zero. And in fact, I prefer a 100% apps script-based solution (so, using my current formula in apps script with `setFormula()` is not an option, either!) to protect my sheet from unwanted mistakes by users.

**Any idea how to tackle this?**

**PS:** Here´s the not so efficient formula, in case somebody might ask for it:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(H6,"[a-zA-Z+/–=:-]*",""))
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Comment: In your expected values, for example, a space like `0431 84500`, `040 63305 5040` and `040 853 123 48` is required to be left?

Comment: @Tanaike - Yes, a space is expected to be left like `0431 84500`, `040 63305 5040` and `040 853 123 48`.

Comment: @Tanaike Have I clearly answered your question? Or you need more information? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a Regex Expression to remove any letter and special characters.
I also used TRIM to remove any whitespace that's not necessary on the number

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[a-zA-Z+/–=:-]*",""))
```

Check this [article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) to see how the function works